# What exactly is Korosensei?

Tags: assassination-classroom

He was born on Earth but moves at incredible speeds, has incredible powers and looks very different in comparison to a human. What is he and how did he become like that?

Answer (score 1):

He was being experimented on , and yes he was a mere human , and also a failed experiment 
It will all be revealed in the anime if you keep watching

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.

Comment: ansatsukyoshitsu.fandom.com/wiki/Korosensei